# How to understand output of TSOP4838 IR receiver?

Tags: 555, infrared, optoelectronics

I am testing the output of the following basic IR transmitter/receiver circuits and not getting the result I thought I would.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRWmkq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have tested the output of the 555 astable circuit and DMM confirms OK (I have a trim pot to control).

When I close SW1, DMM shows momentary drop in voltage at Vout of receiver (approx 3.3V) but if I hold it closed, DMM returns to reading Vout = 4.5V.

I thought I would see Vout = 0V for the duration that SW1 is closed.  What is the expected response and what do I have to change to achieve that?

Comment: What frequency are you using?

Comment: 38 kHz - is that not clear from the schematic?  I'm pretty new to this forum so if I've expressed myself wrong please advise, thank you.

Comment: To be precise, DMM reads 37.95 kHz

Comment: Remember to add a link to the datasheet https://www.vishay.com/docs/82459/tsop48.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the expected response and what do I have to change to achieve
> that?

The expected response is *one* short output pulse from TSOP4838 starting from 4.5V to GND...when the LED is pulsing *continuously* at 38 kHz.
The problem is that TSOP4838 adapts to a continuous 38 kHz, in a similar way that your eye adapts to dim moonlight at night, and bright sunlight during day. Its adaptation is quite short, so that it quickly gets used to *constant* 38kHz and returns to its idle state of 4.5V after just one pulse.

What is needed is short bursts of 38kHz, separated by no light output:
[image: input LED, output pulses timing]

Comment: Am guessing your application runs afoul of IR remote sensors whose block diagram shows a block called **AGC** (automatic gain control). You *might* want TSSP4038 proximity sensor - it works at 38 kHz too, but seems to me that the data sheet suggests continuous 38 kHz gives a continuous low digital output. Its block diagram shows no AGC block. Having no AGC might stop adaptation. It may be that sensing range is somewhat shorter than those employing the AGC block.

Comment: As I put in comment to @Justme, I believe I could feed a PNP + bistable to achieve continuous high output.  Alternatively I will check datasheet for 4038.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The TSOP4838 just does not work like you expect. It is not designed to receive continuous long burst of 38 kHz but to filter it out.

The TSOP4838 will filter out continuous signals at any frequecy. It reads in the data sheet.

So for long enough burst of 38 kHz, it will start ignoring it.

The module has an AGC (automatic gain control) to adjust itself to adapt tp varying lighting conditions. That is why the 38 kHz burst must be short enough to be detected, and that's why there must be a long enough gap between bursts to allow the detection to stay at ambient level. So the part will adapt to long burst being present.

The point is to send bursts of 38 kHz and then a pause to allow the TSOP4838 to stay sensitive enough for the next burst. The suggested minimum and maximum burst lengths and minimum gap between bursts are in the data sheet.

These parts (TSOP4838, TSOP1738, etc) are for remote control receiving, not for detecting a break of continuous 38 kHz beam.

Comment: Thank you, I will check that - is that different to 1738?  In which case I bought the wrong component.  Will report back...

Comment: TSOP1738 will also reject continuous 38 kHz.

Comment: You are right.  I took an application from the net and the wording was such that I misunderstood what the application was designed to achieve.  Now I read it again with this in mind I see it can be interpreted as you describe.  And this ties with the datasheet. 
 It's not a big deal as for my application I could feed a bistable for example.  But thank you very much for the answer.